# Possible reasons for semicolon before underscore in variable name in C

Tags: c, syntax

In [this tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php) about socket programming in C, I stumbled over the following line:

```
bzero((char *) &serv;_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

For some reason, the variable `serv_addr` is written as `serv;_addr` when it is passed as reference. It looks like a typo (and also does not seem to compile with standard flags), however this usage is consistent throughout the whole code - whenever a variable name that contains an underscore is passed as reference, a semicolon is inserted before the underscore:

```
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv;_addr,
    sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR on binding");
[...]
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
    (struct sockaddr *) &cli;_addr, &clilen;);
[... and some more occurences]
```

This consistent usage of (to my knowledge, and gcc seems to agree) invalid syntax kept me wondering if there is some explanation for this phenomenon.

Has anyone seen code like this before? Any ideas how such code could accidentally be generated?

Comment: Wow! You found garbage on the internet!  ;-)

Comment: It may be a feature of the code being inserted as HTML into a web page.

Comment: It doesn't compile. You have exactly zero reasons for giving the entire thing any further consideration. This appears to arise from some failed attempt to provide XML character definitions.

Comment: You need to know just one tutorial about [Unix Network Programming](http://kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html). And that is the one written by [W. Richard Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens). God rest his soul!

Comment: It looks like a failed attempt at "normalising" ampersands, turning every sequence of _ampersand-followed-by-some-letters_ from the source into _ampersand-followed-by-letters-**and-a-semicolon**_ in the HTML (as well as, or subsequently, turning the `&` into `&amp;`). Another example is `(struct sockaddr *) &cli;_addr, &clilen;);` where `clilen` is also affected but doesn't have an underscore.

Comment: @TripeHound This looks like the culprit. Mind to add it as answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with underscores (`_`); instead, it looks like a failed attempt at normalising ampersands (`&`). The ampersand-construct is used in HTML to represent special characters using (among other forms) `&name;`. E.g. `&lt;` for `<`, `&quot;` for `"` and `&amp;` for `&` itself.

It appears that every sequence of *ampersand-followed-by-letters* in the original source-code has been replaced by *ampersand-followed-by-letters-**and-a-semicolon*** in the HTML (presumably in the mistaken belief that these were "*unterminated*" ampersand-constructs). Another example from the source-code demonstrates this:

```
(struct sockaddr *) &cli;_addr, &clilen;);
```

here both `&cli_addr` and `&clilen` have added semicolons, even though the latter does not include an underscore.

At the same time, or in a subsequent "clean-up", the ampersands themselves have been converted to `&amp;`, as can be seen in the HTML source of the line shown above:

```
(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &amp;cli;_addr, &amp;clilen;);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone seen code like this before?

Not me.

> Any ideas how such code could accidentally be generated?

Find and replace operation.

The authot found what he wanted to replace and accidentatly replaced it with `serv;_addr`, which was automatically used in all the occurences of the original string.

Comment: There is also `&cli;_addr`, so just a faulty find and replace on `&serv;_addr` does not explain the issue.